# IE7 select box dissapearing when setting css

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a div (with a transparent background) with a z-index of 1 on top of some select boxes.

In all browsers except for IE7 this displays and functions correctly. **In IE7 the select boxes appear but are not able to be clicked or changed.**

In IE7 the only workaround is to set the div containing the background to z-index -1. This then causes problems with display or the other box in other browsers.

If I do this rule (attempting workaround)

```
select{
position:relative;
z-index:1000;
}
```

All select boxes will disappear in IE7.

What can I do?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using this `z-index` value?

Comment: To make the select box function correctly. I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this with a conditional statement for IE7.

In IE7 -

```
z-index:-1;
```

All other browsers -

```
z-index:1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're doing. Ok. A tip on this type of thing? Don't try and do it yourself!

There are lots of modal windows out there that you can use to overlay a div element on a window and add content to it. Some will grey out the background, some will just float over your content. Do a bit of searching, you'll find one that suits your needs.

The reason you should do this is that select elements are operating system form elements, not web form elements (this is a real pain in the behind). This means that they don't behave in the same way as standard html block elements (they're special and like to be treated special). For this reason, they will always appear as a top level item (even if they are not as in your case). You could write a load of javascript to change the DOM and work around this, but it's already been done.

I know it's probably not what you wanted to hear, but if you do this search, you'll save yourself a lot of heartache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem I am having is that they are not appearing at the top level in IE7 and I want them to. The div that is on top of them is a "swirl" that sits in the bottom right of the page. It is transparent in order to allow for different colored background images. (blame the designer)